# OpenGL - difficulty with constructing shapes

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, lwjgl

I'm starting work on a simple shape-batching system for my 3D engine that will enable me to draw lines and rectangles, etc... with a lower draw call count. I think I've got the basic ideas figured out for the most part, but I'm having problems when I try to draw multiple objects (currently just lines with a thickness you can specify).

Here's a screenshot to show you what I mean:[image: primitive issue]

I'm using indexed rendering with `glDrawElements`, and two VBOs to represent the vertex data - one for positions, and one for colours.
I construct a line for my shape-batcher by specifying start and end points, like so:

```
    shapeRenderer.begin();
    shapeRenderer.setViewMatrix(viewMatrix);
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);

    shapeRenderer.setCurrentColour(0, 1f, 0);
    shapeRenderer.drawLine(2, 2, 5, 2);

    shapeRenderer.setCurrentColour(0, 1f, 1f);
    shapeRenderer.drawLine(2, 5, 5, 5);
    shapeRenderer.end();
```

The first line, represented in green in the screenshot, shows perfectly. If I draw only one line it's completely fine. If I were to draw only the second line it would show perfectly as well.

When I call `drawLine` the following code executes, which I use to compute directions and normals:

```
private Vector2f temp2fA = new Vector2f();
private Vector2f temp2fB = new Vector2f();
private Vector2f temp2fDir = new Vector2f();
private Vector2f temp2fNrm = new Vector2f();
private Vector2f temp2fTMP = new Vector2f();
private boolean flip = false;

public void drawLine(float xStart, float yStart, float xEnd, float yEnd){
    resetLineStates();

    temp2fA.set(xStart, yStart);
    temp2fB.set(xEnd, yEnd);

    v2fDirection(temp2fA, temp2fB, temp2fDir);
    v2fNormal(temp2fDir, temp2fNrm);

    float halfThickness = currentLineThickness / 2;

    //System.out.println("new line called");

    v2fScaleAndAdd(temp2fB, temp2fNrm, -halfThickness, temp2fTMP);
    pushVertex(temp2fTMP);

    v2fScaleAndAdd(temp2fB, temp2fNrm, halfThickness, temp2fTMP);
    pushVertex(temp2fTMP);

    v2fScaleAndAdd(temp2fA, temp2fNrm, halfThickness, temp2fTMP);
    pushVertex(temp2fTMP);

    v2fScaleAndAdd(temp2fA, temp2fNrm, -halfThickness, temp2fTMP);
    pushVertex(temp2fTMP);

    //System.out.println(indexCount + " before rendering.");

    int index = indexCount;

    pushIndices(index, index + 1, index + 3);
    pushIndices(index + 1, index + 2, index + 3);


    //System.out.println(indexCount + " after rendering.");
}
private void resetLineStates(){
    temp2fA.set(0);
    temp2fB.set(0);
    temp2fDir.set(0);
    temp2fNrm.set(0);
    temp2fTMP.set(0);
}
```

`pushIndices` is the following function:

```
private void pushIndices(int i1, int i2, int i3){
    shapeIndices.add(i1);
    shapeIndices.add(i2);
    shapeIndices.add(i3);
    indexCount += 3;
}
```

And `pushVertex` works like so:

```
private void pushVertex(float x, float y, float z){
    shapeVertexData[vertexDataOffset] = x;
    shapeColourData[vertexDataOffset] = currentShapeColour.x;

    shapeVertexData[vertexDataOffset + 1] = y;
    shapeColourData[vertexDataOffset + 1] = currentShapeColour.y;

    shapeVertexData[vertexDataOffset + 2] = z;
    shapeColourData[vertexDataOffset + 2] = currentShapeColour.z;

    //System.out.println("\tpushed vertex: " + data.x + ", " + data.y + ", 0");

    vertexDataOffset += 3;
}
```

I'm using the following fields to store vertex data and such - this is all sub-buffered to a VBO when I flush the batch. If the vertex data arrays have not had to grow in size, I will sub-buffer them to their respective VBO, likewise with the element buffer, otherwise if they have had to grow then I re-buffer the VBO to fit.

```
private float[] shapeVertexData;
private float[] shapeColourData;
private int vertexDataOffset;

private ArrayList<Integer> shapeIndices;
private int indexCount;
```

When I use my debugger in IDEA, the vertex data appears completely correct in the arrays I'm constructing, but when I explore it in RenderDoc, it's wrong. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong to get these results, and obviously the first two vertices appear completely fine even for the second rectangle, but the others are totally wrong.
[image: renderdoc vs IDEA debugger]

I'm confident that my shaders are not the problem, as they're very simple, but here they are:
`shape_render.vs` (vertex shader):

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColour;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

flat out vec3 shapeFill;

void main(){
    shapeFill = aColour;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(aPosition.x, aPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

`shape_render.fs` (fragment shader):

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColour;

in vec3 shapeFill;

void main(){
    fragColour = vec4(shapeFill, 1);
}
```

I think I've just about explained it to the best of my knowledge, any insight would be greatly appreciated. I've already checked and determined I'm enabling the necessary vertex arrays, etc... and rendering the correct amount of indices (12):
[image: correct index count]

Thanks so much for having a look at this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after thinking about it for a while longer. It was to do with how I was specifying the indices. I was using the correct amount of indices however specifying them incorrectly. 
For arguments sake to construct a triangle, the first one would have an index count of 0, and with four vertices, the indices would be 1,2,3 and 2,3,1 (for example). However for each new triangle I was starting the index count at the old count plus six, which makes sense for addressing an array, but because each rectangle only specified four vertices, I was pointing indices at data that didn’t exist. 
So instead of using indexCount += 3 each time I pushed indices, I’ll get the current count of vertices instead and build my indices from that.